# Remove or prevent launch of winebrowser. (Kubuntu/KDE plasma 5)

Tags: kde, wine, kubuntu

On my Kubuntu 18.04 LTS computer, WINE's inbuilt browser "winebrowser" appears bugged. When launched, it gets stuck in an infinite launch loop, spawning winebrowser after winebrowser after winebrowser. The only way to fix is to get into (h)top and kill the parent process.

I need WINE for very few things, but I have absolutely ZERO need for winebrowser to ever launch. How do I remove or disable it completely?

I've used WINE's regedit to remove any keys that reference the application. Now I just need to get KDE to forget about it too.

Comment: May this helps (sometimes me): Check: `Wintrick` > `wineprefix` > `Change settings` > `Prevent windbg from launching when an unhandled exception occurs`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wine#Unregister_existing_Wine_file_associations has some additional information about this issue which still occurs with Kubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 0):

Winebrowser usually opens when I open PDFs, so I'm going to assume it's the same thing going on with you.

First, go on the KDE Settings app. Search for File Associations.
When you opened File Associations, search for the file extensions that trigger winebrowser. Since PDFs are our example, click on PDFs.
Then, you'll see winebrowser sitting on top of the Application Preference Order. You can move it down, but I much rather kill off the source so just remove it. While you're at it, add/move the app that you like to open PDFs at the front.
Click Apply to save changes, and you're done.

Then just search anything else winebrowser might associate itself with (usually document files or html) and manually remove them from the file associations.